# Javaee asyncContext object creating a new thread after dispatching

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-ee-6, asynchronous

I have the following code:

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/Servlet1", asyncSupported=true)
public class Servlet1 extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Servlet1 doGet ..");
        AsyncContext ac =  request.startAsync();
        System.out.println(request.isAsyncStarted());
        ac.dispatch("/Servlet2");
        System.out.println("Servlet1 doGet after dispatch ..");
}

}

@WebServlet("/Servlet2")
public class Servlet2 extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Servlet2 doGet ..");
}

}
```

Notice the following output:

```
Servlet1 doGet ..
true
Servlet1 doGet after dispatch ..
Servlet2 doGet ..
```

Notice the last 2 output lines?

I was expecting (just like a forward request dispatcher)

```
Servlet2 doGet 
Servlet1 doGet after dispatch ..
```

Seems like ac.dispatch has created a new thread.
Any idea on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior is [described in the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html#dispatch%28%29)

> This **method returns immediately after passing the request and response
>   objects to a container managed thread**, on which the dispatch operation
>   will be performed. If this method is called before the
>   container-initiated dispatch that called startAsync has returned to
>   the container, the dispatch operation will be delayed until after the
>   container-initiated dispatch has returned to the container.

This makes sense, since you are in an asynchronous context.

Comment: Thanks. The 2nd part 'If this method is called before the container-initiated dispatch that called startAsync ..', if i'm reading it correctly, there is a dispatcher object and this object (plus all other dispatcher objects) must return to its container before this particular dispatch code can starts in asychnronous mode? Did i get this right?

Comment: @yapkm01 My understanding is: if the `dispatch()` call was executed inside the original Thread handling the request and that thread hasn't completed handling, then the container will wait for it to end before initiating the `dispatch` from the `AsyncContext`.

Comment: So in short (based on my code), ac.dispatch() in servlet1 will only kick off when servlet1 is done. If not ac.dispatch() will have to wait till servlet1 is done. Rite?

Comment: @yapkm01 When the Thread handling the first request finishes handling, yes.

Comment: I have another question. According to asyncContext API, you can dispatch eventhough a response been committed. In a normal requestDispatcher (forward,include) once a response is committed it's a done deal. You cannot dispatch anymore. But for asyn, why is this allowed? Is it because it caters for server push where you can push a response (eg. chat) to a client as many times as you want (where i think committed response is irrelevant for server push)?

Comment: The javadoc says `There can be at most one asynchronous dispatch operation per asynchronous cycle, which is started by a call to one of the ServletRequest.startAsync methods. Any attempt to perform an additional asynchronous dispatch operation within the same asynchronous cycle will result in an IllegalStateException.` To tell you the truth I haven't tested any of this. I'll try to take another look tonight.